# Pandas PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. Whats the efficient solution?

Tags: pandas, insert, concatenation

Here is a generic code representing what is happening in my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dic = {}

for i in np.arange(0,10):
    dic[str(i)] = df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(5000, 20)), 
                                    columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'))
    
df_out = pd.DataFrame(index = df.index)

for i in np.arange(0,10):
    df_out['A_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['A'].astype('int')
    df_out['D_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['D'].astype('int')
    df_out['H_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['H'].astype('int')
    df_out['I_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['I'].astype('int')
    df_out['M_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['M'].astype('int')
    df_out['O_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['O'].astype('int')
    df_out['Q_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['Q'].astype('int')
    df_out['R_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['R'].astype('int')
    df_out['S_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['S'].astype('int')
    df_out['T_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['T'].astype('int')
    df_out['C_'+str(i)] = dic[str(i)]['C'].astype('int')
```

You will notice that as soon as df_out (output) numbers of inseted columns exceed 100 I get the following warning:

*PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider using pd.concat instead*

The question is how could I use:

```
pd.concat()
```

And still have the custom column name that depens on the dictionary key ?

**IMPORTANT: I still would like to keep a specific column selections, not all of them.
Like in the example: A, D , H , I etc...**

**SPECIAL EDIT (based on Corralien's answer)**

```
cols = {'A': 'float',
        'D': 'bool'}

out = pd.DataFrame()
for c, df in dic.items():
    for col, ftype in cols.items():
        out = pd.concat([out,df[[col]].add_suffix(f'_{c}')], 
                        axis=1).astype(ftype)
```

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a comprehension with `pd.concat`:

```
cols = {'A': 'float', 'D': 'bool'}

out = pd.concat([df[cols].astype(cols).add_prefix(f'{k}_')
                    for k, df in dic.items()], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output:
     0_A   0_D    1_A   1_D    2_A   2_D    3_A   3_D
0  116.0  True  396.0  True  944.0  True  398.0  True
1  128.0  True  102.0  True  561.0  True   70.0  True
2  982.0  True  613.0  True  822.0  True  246.0  True
3  830.0  True  366.0  True  861.0  True  906.0  True
4  533.0  True  741.0  True  305.0  True  874.0  True
```

Comment: Not a problem. The important thing is that it works for you even if you use my solution at the end :-P. lol

Comment: Where should i add the .astype('int') in your answer ? Before/after add_prefix ?

Comment: Use it at the end of `pd.concat`.

Comment: I now have a specific format to apply for each columns I would like to extract.
I could do something based on what you have done (see in question special edit).
I am just wondering if you would have done it in a "sexier" way ?

Comment: I updated my answer. In this case, use your dict to cast dtypes before `add_prefix`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with flatten `MultiIndex` in `map`:

```
cols = ['A','D']
df_out = pd.concat({k: v[cols] for k, v in dic.items()}, axis=1).astype('int')
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')

print (df_out)
   A_0  D_0  A_1  D_1  A_2  D_2  A_3  D_3
0  116  341  396  502  944  483  398  839
1  128  621  102   70  561  656   70  169
2  982   44  613  775  822  379  246   25
3  830  987  366  481  861  632  906  676
4  533  349  741  410  305  422  874   19
```

Comment: If I am right your anwer assumes that all columns from all dfs in dictionary are taken. 
I would only like to take some specific columns but not all of them. At least the specific columns to be picked are the same accross all dfs in the dictionary.

Comment: Lets say I would only like to have A and D, so the results would have the following columns:
A_0 D_0, A_1 D_1, A_2 D_2, A_3 D_3,

Comment: @plonfat - added to answer.

Comment: Any idea on why a simple df['new_col'] = col is not efficient ?
To me it is so much easier/lighter to write...

Comment: @plonfat - It is many iteration, if only few then it is perfect.