# 'PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented' whilst creating a dataframe of with 10K columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have viewed similar solutions like the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70079811/pandas-performancewarning-dataframe-is-highly-fragmented-whats-the-efficient-s) but I can't get it to work on my implementation.

| referee | referee_phone_number | referred_by |
| --- | --- | --- |
| referee_A | 01500600 | Person A_fraudster |
| referee_B | 01500601 | Person A_fraudster |
| referee_C | 01500602 | Person A_fraudster |
| referee_D | 01500603 | Person A_fraudster |
| referee_E | 01501928 | Person B_non_fraudster |
| referee_F | 01779810 | Person B_non_fraudster |

Using code below:

```
from similarity.normalized_levenshtein import NormalizedLevenshtein
normalized_levenshtein = NormalizedLevenshtein()

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': df.referee_phone_number})
numbers = df.referee_phone_number.tolist()

for i in numbers:
    df[i] = df.referee_phone_number.apply(lambda x: normalized_levenshtein.similarity(x, i))
df.set_index('numbers', inplace=True)
df = df.where((df[numbers] > 0.5) & (df[numbers] < 1), other=0)
df = df.max(axis=1)
df = df.reset_index()
df.rename(columns={ 0: 'max_similarity_within_dataset'}, inplace=True)
df
```

However, I am coming into problems at this point in the code where the loop is:

```
for i in numbers:
    df[i] = df.referee_phone_number.apply(lambda x: normalized_levenshtein.similarity(x, i))
```

Which is supposed to first generate this matrix:

| numbers | 019500600 | 019500601 | 019500602 | 019500603 | 014501928 | 016779810 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 019500600 | 1 | 0.888889 | 0.888889 | 0.888889 | 0.444444 | 0.333333 |
| 019500601 | 0.888889 | 1 | 0.888889 | 0.888889 | 0.444444 | 0.222222 |
| 019500602 | 0.888889 | 0.888889 | 1 | 0.888889 | 0.444444 | 0.222222 |
| 019500603 | 0.888889 | 0.888889 | 0.888889 | 1 | 0.444444 | 0.222222 |
| 014501928 | 0.444444 | 0.444444 | 0.444444 | 0.444444 | 1 | 0.222222 |
| 016779810 | 0.333333 | 0.222222 | 0.222222 | 0.222222 | 0.222222 | 1 |

My code implementation works in small number of rows, but in the case of doing it for 11K phone numbers it means creating a matrix that is 11K*11K. I hit a performanceWarning:

```
<ipython-input-56-f4893743bb4a>:11: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider using pd.concat instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  df[i] = df.referee_phone_number.apply(lambda x: normalized_levenshtein.similarity(x, i))
```

If there any way I can write my code more efficiently?

Comment: Why compute all combinations without grouping by `referred_by` column?

Comment: You are right. I will first compute the matrix, select the max value after that, row by row, giving me the max similarity (>0.5, <1) for each number in the index. I will later join it back to ```df```, allowing me to groupby average for each ```referred_by``` ID, current problem is though, that the computation of the matrix itself is taking too long

Comment: I mean group by `referred_by` then create the matrix for each group. For `Person A_fraudster` is it necessary to compare `019500600` (first row) and `016779810` (last row) because it's not the same `referred_by`?

Comment: I edited my question for clarity above, should give a better picture. How do I go about doing a ```groupby``` on ```referred_by``` first? since grouping by an aggregation will cause me to lose information about the phone numbers? Could you explain please?